# How to get the lat/long from highest point in a polygon, on earth engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I have a polygon (fusion table) and I need to discover which is the highest point from point. Here's what I have done until now:

```
var elevation = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');
var rainierWaypoints =
    ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1oCYHTwkJhzDdJi3sabCm-BFyTwhu7N2HuQPpceBv');

Map.addLayer(elevation.clip(rainierWaypoints), {min:0, max:300, palette:['000000',"ffffff"]},"elevation2");
var chart = ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image: elevation,
  regions: rainierWaypoints,
  scale: 200,
  xProperty: 'name'
});
chart.setOptions({
  title: 'Propriedade',
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Elevation (meters)'
  },
  legend: 'none',
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4
});
var options = {
  title: 'Altitude',
  fontSize: 12,
  hAxis: {title: 'Frequência'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Altitude'},
  series: {
    0: {color: 'blue'}
  }
};

var histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram(elevation, rainierWaypoints, 30)
    .setSeriesNames(['blue'])
    .setOptions(options);
print(histogram);

print(chart);

Map.centerObject(rainierWaypoints);
Map.addLayer(rainierWaypoints, {color: 'FF0000'});
```

Here's the fusion table that I'm using as example.
https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1oCYHTwkJhzDdJi3sabCm-BFyTwhu7N2HuQPpceBv#map:id=3

Comment: You need to share your fusiontable - otherwise we won't be able to run the script.

Comment: @Kersten I updated the question with the fusion table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only solution, but works fine. It'd get messy if there is more than one pixel with same height (that problem would have another solution I think). The code:

```js
elevation = elevation.clip(rainierWaypoints)

// Pixel position
var pixel_pos = ee.Image.pixelLonLat();

// Highest elevation
var high = elevation.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), rainierWaypoints, 10).get('elevation');

// Leave only the highest pixel (mask)
var highest = elevation.eq(ee.Image.constant(high));

// Add pixel position to the mask
var highest_point_image = elevation.addBands(pixel_pos).mask(highest);

// Get Lon & Lat of that pixel (mean to be in the middle)
var highest_point = highest_point_image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), rainierWaypoints, 10);

// Create a point using Lat & Lon
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([highest_point.get('longitude'), highest_point.get('latitude')]);
Map.addLayer(point, {}, 'Highest point')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a masked image (similar to Rodrigo's approach) with [ee.Image.reduceToVectors()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagereducetovectors) to find the highest areas. Note that you many want to increase the value of MAX_PIXELS when analyzing very large regions.

```js
// Set the number maximum number of pixels to sample. Increase this number
// to increase the accuracy when analyzing large regions.
var MAX_PIXELS = 1e8;

// Declare an elevation dataset to use.
var elevation = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

// Area around Sao Paulo, Brazil.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-41.3, -24.0],
          [-42.6, -21.0],
          [-49.5, -18.9],
          [-53.4, -22.3],
          [-47.9, -26.2]]]);

// Find the highest elevation in a specified region-of-interest (roi).
var highest_elevation = elevation.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: roi,
    bestEffort: true,
    maxPixels: MAX_PIXELS,
}).get('elevation');

// Created a masked image of only the highest elevations.
var highest_mask = elevation.eq(ee.Image.constant(highest_elevation));

// Create features from the non-masked high elevation areas.
var max_elevation_features = elevation.mask(highest_mask).reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi, 
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
  bestEffort: true,
  maxPixels: MAX_PIXELS,
});

// Print the feature information to the console.
print('max_elevation_features', max_elevation_features);

// Add Layers to the interactive map.
Map.centerObject(max_elevation_features);
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'white'}, 'Region of Interest');
Map.addLayer(max_elevation_features, {color:'red'}, 'Max Elevation Areas');
```

This approach also works on areas where there are multiple locations with the same elevation. To demonstrate this, use the following region (in the salt flats of Utah, USA):

```js
// Flat area with multiple equivalent high points.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-113.40306, 40.74333],
          [-113.40306, 40.74255],
          [-113.40107, 40.74255],
          [-113.40107, 40.74333]]]);
```